# Criticism or criticisms

Tags: american-english, plural-forms

As in the dictionary, the plural form of criticism is criticisms, but I'm confused by these examples :

> he received a lot of criticism
>
> it has attracted criticism

Can *criticism* also be used for the plural form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criticism can be used both as a *countable* and *uncountable* noun. This is mentioned in its [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criticism), for example.

In this sentence:

> he received a lot of criticism

It's not that "criticism" is plural here, but rather it's being used as an uncountable noun. Much like saying "He received a lot of love and money" (you don't say *loves or *monies in this context)

For contrast, here's an example of *criticisms* being used as a countable noun:

> There were several criticisms he took to heart.

Comment: Thanks, your answer's good enough for me, but in my opinion, your example of love and money is not very approriate because they're uncountable nouns and are only used in the singular tense

Comment: But that's why I used them. As examples of other uncountable nouns. "Criticism" is also being used like that in that example.

Comment: @f855a864 Both *lots of* and *a lot of* can be used before uncountable and (plural) countable nouns. For example, I believe you must've heard this one before, "We have a lot of work to do". The word *work* there is uncountable. -- *a lot of water, a lot of time, a lot of pain, a lot of money, etc.* are all grammatical.